# How do I disable adobe flash "hardware acceleration" in terminal

Tags: kubuntu, flash

I can't uncheck the box for settings to disable hardware acceleration in Flash. Can it be done in terminal or in Firefox somehow?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please tell why do you want to disable it. Are there some problems when acceleration enabled?

Comment: I think it can cause problems on older machines but I'm not absolutely sure...

Answer (score 3):

Their are two ways you can disable hardware acceleration for flash, the terminal way is to create a file called `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` and add the following line:

```
EnableLinuxHWVideoDecode=0
```

**The 2nd method** I would recommend is opening a youtube video and going into full screen, right-clicking Settings and unticking Enable Hardware Acceleration.

If by some chance it doesn't let you untick, use the tab key to move between the buttons and press Space to do it for you.